# How to use core data for frequently updated database

Tags: sqlite, google-maps, core-data

i want to create an app with a database of about 500 contacts that will include: names, location, emails, etc.

also when a user launches app, it will grab the users location and show you the contacts that are nearby within a 100 mile radius, kinda like yelp app

the database will get added onto every few weeks, maybe 10 or so contacts.

my question is how to make it so that my app's most recent database updates when the user launches the app.

I've been looking around and searching, but cant find a clear solution, can i use core data or should i go a different route, and if I use core data or don't, how do i go about doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is definitely the way to go.

With a few hundred or thousand records, you will find that the import / update will be lightening fast, indeed so fast that maybe you do not even need concurrency. I have imported about 20.000 address book-like records in less than 2 seconds on an iPhone 3GS.

The magnitude of the updates you mention is trivial. Even if they were downloaded from the web, it will cost you a mere split second.

Additionally, you will hardly have to worry about memory management because Core Data is very good at that behind the scenes.

Comment: But how do I make it so that the app updates to the most recent database ? Do I need to store the database on a web server , I can't find any details on how to do this. My database will be updating frequently . I can't find any instructions or tutorials on how to do this

Comment: That is a different question altogether. You could add an `updated` attribute to your entity. Then you do a fetch to find the youngest record and ask your server for all the records that are even younger. This will be just an incremental update. There are many answers here on SOF of how to download, say, JSON and store the result in Core Data.

Comment: would this tutorial here be the way to go? http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

Comment: Yes - raywenderlich is very good. Please don't forget to upvote / tick this answer if it was helpful.